# Redirect of URL with parameter not working as expected

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am wondering which kind of redirect-rule might bring
`http://www.gesetzesweb.de/StrRehaG.html+target=`
to redirect to
`https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/`

`http://www.gesetzesweb.de/StrRehaG.html` is already correctly redirecting to `https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/`,

but `http://www.gesetzesweb.de/StrRehaG.html+target=` is falling back to the default `https://www.anwalt.org/gesetze/`

Hereby you can see which redirect rules are set in place in the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/StrRehaG.html?$ https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/StrRehaG.html%20target=?$ https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/
RedirectMatch 301 / https://www.anwalt.org/gesetze/
```

Does anybody have any clue?

I tried to put

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/StrRehaG.html%20target=?$ https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/`
after
`RedirectMatch 301 / https://www.anwalt.org/gesetze/`
without success

Thank you very much in advance for any valuable hint.

Comment: Where does "WordPress" fit into this? Since your 3rd rule redirects everything-else and you would seem to be redirecting to an external domain I can't see how the "WordPress" tag is relevant here? (If you are using WordPress then `RedirectMatch` might not be the correct tool for the job.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/StrRehaG.html%20target=?$ https://www.anwalt.org/strafrechtliches-rehabilitierungsgesetz-strrehag/
> ```

A `+` in the URL-path part of the URL is a literal `+`, not an encoded *space*. (`+` is only an encoded *space* when used in the query string part of the URL, but you still wouldn't be matching against `%20`.) So the regex should be like the following instead:

```
^/StrRehaG\.html\+target=$
```

Note that the literal `+` needs to be backslash-escaped in the regex to negate its special meaning as a regex *quantifier*. Likewise, the literal `.` should also be backslash-escaped. The trailing `?` would seem to be redundant, based on your examples. You can combine the first two rules with the following regex:

```
^/StrRehaG\.html(\+target=)?$
```

This makes the trailing `+target=` part optional. So it matches both `/StrRehaG\.html` and `/StrRehaG\.html+target=`.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> ```

Note that `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive. `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite) is therefore not required.